# ContentView does not have a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am just starting with xamarin to play around with it, and thought xamarin forms would be a good place to start to learn.
I began following this tutorial:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/creating/

which has a line as follows:
`contentView.ControlTemplate = (originalTemplate) ? tealTemplate : aquaTemplate;`

The problem for me is that my local code says that ContentView does not contain a definition for ControlTemplate.

The only xamarin related using statement in the document is:
`using Xamarin.Forms`;

I have the following declaration at the top of the class aswell:
`ControlTemplate mainTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(MainTemplate));`

This has the error 'The type or namespace ControlTemplate could not be found'

When I try rebuild it throws that as an error, so it isn's just VS 2015 being slow.
I downloaded xamarin yesterday.
My JDK is 1.7.0_55.
My android SDK was downloaded yesterday (don't know where to find version)
My android NDk is version r10e.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Nuget manager in VS to be sure you have the latest version of the Xamarin Forms packages.

Comment: Only one NuGet package shows, Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482, with no option of updating or viewing other versions.

Comment: Thankyou for that.
Not sure why it installed at a lower version.